# joint probability distribution independent variables

Tags: probability

I got a problem with my upcomming exam. There is no lecture this semester, so I cant ask anyone. I really could need help, to understand, what is going on, and how to get the task done correctly. I think, in theory, it should be easy, i am just completely lost.

I got given the joint probability distribution of three binary variables $A, B$ and $C$.

- $P(a_1,b_1,c_1) = 0,0315$
- $P(a_1,b_1,c_2) = 0,0585$
- $P(a_1,b_2,c_1) = 0,1260$
- $P(a_1,b_2,c_2) = 0,2340$
- $P(a_2,b_1,c_1) = 0,0990$
- $P(a_2,b_1,c_2) = 0,0660$
- $P(a_2,b_2,c_1) = 0,2310$
- $P(a_2,b_2,c_2) = 0,1540$

Sadly we never discussed an excercise like this ...

And now I have to show, that random variable $B$ and $C$ are independent (if they are), and if $B$ and $C$ are independent given $A$. If yes, show. If no, show a counter example.

How do i do this? And why do i do, what i do? x.x Pls help!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

You can show $B$ and $C$ are independent if $P(B=b_1,C=c_1)=P(B=b_1) P(C=c_1)$ (and similarly for the other three related patterns, but in fact showing any one is enough)

You can show $B$ and $C$ are independent given $A$ if both $P(B=b_1, C=c_1 \mid A=a_1)=P(B=b_1\mid A=a_1) P(C=c_1\mid A=a_1)$ and  $P(B=b_1, C=c_1 \mid A=a_2)=P(B=b_1\mid A=a_2) P(C=c_1\mid A=a_2)$

If these fail then you have your counter-example

Comment: Hey, thank you for your reply. Sadly i dont have P(B=b1) given. Or P(C=c1). Actually i have non of these. Just the 8, stated top. So i can't calculate this. Any other way? :(

Also, how would i calculate: P(B=b1,C=c1)? The thing right to the = is multiplication. If i got those, i can do it. But the left thing i have no clue how to calculate, even if i had those values. Like the ... "elemental values?" Dunno how they are called :(

Comment: At least i got 0,255 for B1 and 0,4875 for C1, so the right side of the = should be 0,1243. But the left side, is unclear. Could i also check B2 and C2? I mean i have to check ALL values, right? Or just find ONE counterexample? But why should it be enough, to just check B1 and C1?

Comment: Also, how would someone calculate P(B=b1∣A=a1)P(C=c1∣A=a1)? As said, i dont have A1 or B1 given. I need to check how the formula is for P(B=b1∣A=a1) for instance as well. Dont know what tu put where and how yet.

Comment: Your $0.255$ for $P(B=b_1)$  and $0.4875$ for  $P(C=c_1)$.  You can find $P(B=b_1,C=c_1) = 0.0315+0.099 = 0.1305$ which is not $0.1243125$ and so you can conclude $B$ and $C$ are not independent

Comment: $P(B=b_1 \mid A=a_1) = \frac{0.0315+0.0585}{0.0315+0.0585+0.126+0.234}=0.2$ and $P(C=c_1 \mid A=a_1) = \frac{0.0315+0.126}{0.0315+0.0585+0.126+0.234}=0.35$ and $P(B=b_1, C=c_1 \mid A=a_1) = \frac{0.0315}{0.0315+0.0585+0.126+0.234}=0.07$ and $0.2 \times 0.35 = 0.07$ so you can say that conditional on $A=a_1$ you have $B$ and $C$ independent.  Check whether this is also true given  $A=a_2$

Comment: Henry, thank you very much. You are a true saviour! :) I might not understand the reason behind all those calculations, but at least i see the patterns now, which i can use. (i just dont understand statistics at all, but have to do this course ...) One more question tho. If i have to check for A=a2. Do i have to check B=b2|A=a2, or B=b1|A=a2, and for C the same way? Like, why is it enough to just check b1 and c1, and dont care for b2 and c2 at all?

Comment: Because $P(B=b_1)+P(B=b_2)=1$ and there are just two possibilities, and similarly with $C$, you only have to check $(2-1)\times(2-1)=1$ case, and the other will follow.  Similarly with $C$.  It would be more work if there were say five possibilities each for $B$ and for $C$ as you would have to check $(5-1) \times (5-1) =16$ cases